# WPF Datagrid - Multisort Shift Slick use Ctrl Click

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I have a Datagrid in WPF, using an `ICollectionView` I have multisorting on it.

To multisort one would use Shift+Click to sort additional columns, I want to use Ctrl+Click.

How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you catch the key combinations already, as you state, in the `Shift+Click` which calls some method to MultiSort(), I assume? Why not call that method on `Ctrl+Click`?

**EDIT:**
in `Ctrl+Click`, you can sort using vairous techniques:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms745786%28v=vs.90%29.aspx

also there is a good answer post here on stack overflow by `Геннадий-Ванин`, It should be the last answer at this point..

[WPF Datagrid group and sort](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16050211/wpf-datagrid-group-and-sort)

Comment: No it's the default mutli sorting in WPF ICollection's datagrid

Comment: @Smithy, I understand now! Question for you, wouldn't you think that overriding this default behavior would be confusing for the users?

Comment: Updated with a couple of links, hope it'll help.

Comment: well I thought the same, but the client is insisting that the end users are currently using another app that has this behavior.